# Using web service from about 100000 users in the same time

Tags: web-services

I have a web service which will be called from about...let us say 100000 users in the same time (within 3 hours). The services reads and updates the SQL database using Entity Framework 4.1. Here is the code

```
    [WebMethod]
public bool addVotes(string username,string password,int votes)
{
    bool success= false;

    if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password) == true)
    {
        DbContext context = new DbContext();
        AppUsers user = context.AppUsers.Where(x => x.Username.Equals(username)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (user != null)
        {
            user.Votat += votes;
            context.SaveChanges();
            success = true;
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```

The web service will be called from android mobiles(as I said maybe 100000 maybe more maybe less but that`s not important right now). Is there a deadlock possibility or a possibility for things to go wrong?

What will happen when reading from database and what when updating. As one of the answers said: I am updating just the field Vote per each user. If there is any problem with this how do you advice me to correct it.

Thank You in advance :)

Comment: With 100,000 users in 3 hours, I'd say that the potential for deadlock was a near certainty.

Comment: If you're updating the same row multiple times then there is always a possibility for locks to occur.

Comment: I am not updating the same row. I am updating always the same field of a user.

Comment: what`s wrong here to give downvotes ?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fine.

The reason i say that is that as far as i can tell, the only thing that happens when this method is called on behalf of a user is that the vote count (`Votat`) in their row in the database is increased. As long as they are only touching their own row, and not any row that might also be touched by one of the 99999 other users, then there is no contention between users, and this should scale well.

Comment: Well you are saying these and there are two comments saying the opposite :S. Anyway as you said I have tried to change only one field of a user not a row that will be used by the other users in the same time. What about reading in the database? e.g. AppUsers user = context.AppUsers.Where(x => x.Username.Equals(username)).FirstOrDefault();
Is it possibe that while reading a deadlock can occur?

Comment: The precise semantics of locking and so on depend on which database you're using, which you haven't specified. But in general, no, if you're selecting a single row, that should not have an impact on writes to other rows from other transactions.

Comment: Some legacy databases have something called 'lock escalation', in which row-level locks can be escalated to a lock on the whole table, but even that requires a transaction to hold locks on many rows, whereas your code will only ever hold one.

Comment: Even if two transactions did try to lock the same row (eg because they were for the same user), you would not have deadlock, as there is no possibility of the two transactions each holding a different lock that the other one needs to proceed, because there is only one lock involved.

Comment: Thank You for all these answers. Bthw i am using MSSQL. What about the reading part? I am using EF here but I dont know how EF works under the hood. AppUsers user = context.AppUsers.Where(x => x.Username.Equals(username)).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: MS SQL is one of the legacy databases that does lock escalation. But as i said, that shouldn't matter, and you should be fine. As long as there is an index on the username, that query should only take a read lock on a single row.

Comment: There is no index on the username column! Should I put one?

Comment: Yes. You should definitely do that.

Comment: Well thnx indeed. Last question but does this mean that this row Membership.ValidateUser(username, password) requires an index to the password field as well?

Comment: Unlikely. Indeed, hopefully there isn't a password field.

Comment: haha Sorry I was planing to not ask any other question but now I have to ask again? Im afraid that I couldnt understand your last answer :). Should I put an index in the password field as well or not ?

Comment: You do not need an index on the password column. But the point is, you should not (*must* not) simply store passwords in your database. You need to hash the password, and currently the best way to do that is with bcrypt. I don't have time to get into this now (beer calls), but have a read of http://security.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/why-passwords-should-be-hashed/ and *please please please* don't store raw passwords!

Comment: Andersonnoo noo Im not storin raw password. The passwords are actually encrypted. Thnx for the article and for all your answers :)